# Using CS inequality to find maximum of a function

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value, symmetric-polynomials

I am trying to us Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to find the maximum of:
$$|(a^2)(b^2)(a-b)+(b^2)(c^2)(b-c)+(c^2)(a^2)(c-a)|$$
Where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real numbers, and $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$.

What I've tried:

$$a_1=a,\ a_2=b,\ a_3=c$$
$$b_1=b\sqrt{a-b}, \ b_2=c\sqrt{b-c}, \ b_3=a\sqrt{c-a}$$
Which gives:
$$(a^2)(b^2)(a-b)+(b^2)(c^2)(b-c)+(c^2)(a^2)(c-a)\leq(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a-b^3+b-c^3+c-a^3)$$
And I can rearrange and apply the constraints to get
$$(a^2)(b^2)(a-b)+(b^2)(c^2)(b-c)+(c^2)(a^2)(c-a)\leq2(-b^3-c^3-a^3)$$
But I'm not sure where to go from here. How can I use CS to get to an answer here?

Comment: Your CS inequality is wrong, you get $ab^2-b^3$ for $b_1^2$, not $a- b^3$. Furthermore, you need to assume something like $a \ge b \ge c$, and see how this effect $\sqrt{a-b}^2$, $\sqrt{b-c}^2$ and $\sqrt{c-a}^2$ as they are all positive.  And then subsitute $c= -a-b$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=1$, $b=-1$ and $c=0$. Hence, we get a value $2$.
We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, since the condition gives $ab+ac+bc=-1$, we obtain:

$|\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b^2-a^3c^2)|=|(ab+ac+bc)(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)|=|(a-b)(2a+b)(a+2b)|$.

Since the condition gives $a^2+ab+b^2=1$, it remains to prove that
$$4(a^2+ab+b^2)^3\geq(a-b)^2(2a^2+5ab+2b^2)^2$$

which is $(a+b)^2a^2b^2\geq0$. Done!

Comment: Hmmm..., actually $\,a\cdot b+b\cdot c+ c\cdot a=-1\,$ (minus, not $+1$). No big deal, the absolute value is what counts.

Comment: @Wlod AA It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!